# ¿Cómo optimizar código dentro de un foreach C#?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

Tengo el siguiente código, y necesitó que se ejecute en menos tiempo por que existe un gran numero de elementos dentro de esta lista donde se realiza el recorrido.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Código C#:

```
foreach (var item in modelo)
            {
                item.Reclasificacion = item.Descripcion + " - " + tipoDocumento.Where(x => x.Tipo == item.Tipo).Select(x => x.Descripcion).FirstOrDefault();
                item.Nit =(long) encabezadoMovimiento.Where(x => x.Movimiento_ID == item.Movimiento_ID).Select(x => x.Identificacion).FirstOrDefault();
                item.Comprobante2 = encabezadoMovimiento.Where(x => x.Movimiento_ID == item.Movimiento_ID).Select(x => x.Numero ).FirstOrDefault();
                item.Nombre = encabezadoMovimiento.Where(x => x.Movimiento_ID == item.Movimiento_ID).Select(x => x.Nombre).FirstOrDefault();
                item.Tipo = item.Tipo + " - " + encabezadoMovimiento.Where(x => x.Movimiento_ID == item.Movimiento_ID).Select(x => x.Documento_Id ).FirstOrDefault();

            }
```

Comment: Quizá sea más eficiente si el código lo escribes tú en lugar de usar LINQ.

Comment: Podrías comenzar con hacer un solo `Where` a `encabezadoMovimiento` para recuperar el registro y luego asignarlo a las propiedades correspondientes.

Answer (score 1):

Como dijo @Lobos, la forma más fácil de bajar sería solo usar un where para obtener el encabezado y otro para el tipo de documento.

```
  foreach (var item in modelo)//substituir var por tu classe 
        {

            string tipodoc = tipoDocumento.Where(x => x.Tipo == item.Tipo).Select(x => x.Descripcion).FirstOrDefault();//mejor usar el tipo adequado en vez de var si no cambia el tipo de dato
            var encabezMov = encabezadoMovimiento.Where(x => x.Movimiento_ID == item.Movimiento_ID).FirstOrDefault();//substituir var por tu classe

            item.Reclasificacion= item.Descripcion + " - "+tipodoc.Descripcion;
            if (encabezMov == null) {
                //No hemos encontrado los datos
                item.Nit = 0;
                item.Comprobante2 = 0;
                item.Nombre = "";
                item.Tipo = item.Tipo + " - "; 
                    }
            else
            {
                //la hemos encontrado
                item.Nit =(long)encabezMov.Identificacion;
                item.Comprobante2 = encabezMov.Numero;
                item.Nombre = encabezMov.Nombre;
                item.Tipo = item.Tipo + " - "+encabezMov.Documento_Id;
            }
       

        }
```

En caso de que aun te falte otra cosa que puedes hacer es substituir el foreach por un for o while depende de lo que te conviene. Ya que en optimización por el mismo procedimiento de menos a más rápido(en general) Foreach<for<while.

También tienes que tener en cuenta que la operacion de linq es equivalente a:

```
IEnumerable<Object> itenera=new IEnumerable<Object>();
foreach(var item in lista){
    if(item.clausa==cond)
      itenera.add(item);

 }
return  itenera;
```